# Want to monitor Https traffic from google chrome

Tags: google-chrome, https

I want to monitor Https traffic going out from google chrome. 
Is there any possibility to write something in C++ for similar purpose, like some hook.
When I tried to hook in [ws2_32::WSASend](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms742203%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API and load my dll in chrome, it is causing crash. It look like chrome protects hooking of Windows API. I am more interested in APIs not applications like fiddler which can show Https traffic.

I have also seen google's native-client option but does not think it is useful because any extension need to deploy using google web store which is not a possibility in my case.